# java-How do i export data from a java db to a text file

Tags: java, javadb

How can i export data from a javaDB ( found under services tab in netbeans) into a text file?
i'm looking for the easiest possible code. (also i want to use this code in a jframe but means of a button).Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way and the best is manually,  read data from the DB row by row and write them to the txt file line by line. I don't think so that there is a tool or plugin to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is. There are a number of stored procedures called SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_[IMPORT|EXPORT]_* for this kind of thing.

More info can be found in the [Derby Reference Manual](https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/ref/rrefexportproc.html)

and [Derby Server and Administration Guide](https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/adminguide/cadminimport16245.html)

Esp. the section called "Running import and export procedures from JDBC"